# How To Obtain The Correct Differential Gears With Motor Shaft Adapters

Tags: motors, gears

My knowledge in gears in limited to their types (bevel, spur, etc).  I am trying to combine the power/torque of two [DC motors](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/25mm-shaft-universal-tri-motor-mount.html) using a differential gear.

I have a good handle on the idea and design from [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/2778/21402) and [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-transfer-the-power-of-two-motors-onto-a-single-shaft)

The problem I am having now is finding the correct differential gear to use (in term of shaft size, etc).

For a PoC I don't mind using Lego or plastic.  Eventually these two motors will connect via another differential to two other motors (which have their own differential) for a total of 4 to hopefully turn the drive shaft of this [kettcar](https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTc2WDEwMjQ=/z/1zMAAOSwRB5c6AvE/$_72.JPG).

My overarching question is:

1. How/where do I choose the correct differential to use?
2. How do I scale up/down the motor's output shaft to fit into whichever differential gear I end up using?

As to "why" do this:

1. Learning
2. Learning
3. Fun

That said, if this approach is bat-crap crazy, then please feel free to say so and suggest an alternative.

Comment: Look at the **second** answer to [Effective ways to drive a single shaft with multiple motors?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/effective-ways-to-drive-a-single-shaft-with-multiple-motors/2778#2778).  Just use two identical motors, driving the output shaft in parallel through identical gears or belts, and connected in parallel electrically.

Comment: @TimWescott I saw that also, but I saw more answers against that in terms of the motors being identical in their output.

Comment: As long as your motors are the same make & model, and are identically geared, they'll be close enough.